# How to turn of spellchecking in ipywidgets Textarea?

Tags: python, css, ipywidgets

On ipywidgets version 8, I've tried to turn off spellchecking (which is a CSS attribute) like this:

```py
area = ipywidgets.Textarea(rows=10, style={"spellchecking": "false"})
```

But the created widget still gets spellchecked (Chrome 116.0.5845.111)